# Postgres- unequal splitting of rows and assigning value

Tags: postgresql

### I have a table as below,

| id | rank | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 7 | 4 |  |
| 6 | 4 |  |

I want to assign grades to students based on their rank.

```
-grade 1 10% of total students
-grade 2 10%
-grade 3 30%
-grade 4 50% 

1.The **first 10%** of students based on their rank, need to be allocated to grade1.
2.The **next 10%** of students based on their rank, need to be allocated to grade2.
3.The **next 30%** of students based on their rank, need to be allocated to grade3.
4.The **next 50%** of students based on their rank, need to be allocated to grade4.
```

Could someone help with postgres code for the same.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Comment: Within a select statement, "case" is an **expression** as they resolve to a scalar value (i..e they resolve to an expression). A "case statement" is available in Oracle and they are branching mechanisms for procedural code (to my knowledge this is the only true case statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest cross joining to a single row of the grade boundaries which will simplify the **case expression** somewhat. Also I feel that the test for `> 0` is redundant and can be omitted (but re-introduce it if you really want it). Also note that if a condition is met the **case expression** stops at that point, so you can exploit this to further simplify the conditions by only comparing to the upper boundary of any grade range as long as the conditions are in the correct order.

A total of subject marks are calculated and these are ranked ((highest to lowest)) via the rank function. Students can have share a rank value with other students. Using that rank in the order, a row_number is then calculated. This row number is compared to percentages of the student population to be assigned a "grade"

```
of total students         
-----------------
10%  grade 1
10%  grade 2
30%  grade 3
50%  grade 4
```

Note the data must have a larger number of rows than in the sample provided in the question for reasonable results, so I have used 21 rows (see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MSj2KlZb) for details). This data is arbitrary and rank isn't re-calculated just some copy/paste was done.

The row numbers are then used to assign grades, but it is necessary to calculate at which row we change grade assignment. This can be done as follows (but note the percentages are cumulative!):

```
select
      round(c * 0.10) as g1 -- cumulative %
    , round(c * 0.20) as g2 -- cumulative %
    , round(c * 0.50) as g3 -- cumulative %
    , c as g4
from (
      select count(*) * 1.0 as c 
      from mytable -- your source data, may require where clause too
     ) t
```

| g1 | g2 | g3 | g4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 |

That result shows the row numbers at which we change grade levels. e.g. rows <= 2 are grade 1, rows >2 but <= 4 are grade 2, etc. This logic applied to the students:

```
with ranges as (
    select
          round(c * 0.10) as g1 -- cumulative %
        , round(c * 0.20) as g2 -- cumulative %
        , round(c * 0.50) as g3 -- cumulative %
        , c as g4
    from (
          select count(*) * 1.0 as c 
          from mytable -- your source data, may require where clause too
         ) t  )
, students as (
      SELECT
             studentID
           , rank
           , (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rank)) AS row_num
      FROM mytable
  )
select
       *
     ,  case
            when s.row_num <= r.g1 then 1
            when s.row_num <= r.g2 then 2
            when s.row_num <= r.g3 then 3
            when s.row_num <= r.g4 then 4
            else -1
       end as calc_grade
from students s
cross join ranges r
```

| studentid | rank | row_num | g1 | g2 | g3 | g4 | calc_grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 1 |
| 30 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 31 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 51 | 2 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 50 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 40 | 3 | 10 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 11 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 3 |
| 41 | 3 | 12 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 70 | 4 | 13 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 60 | 4 | 14 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 15 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 | 16 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 17 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 61 | 4 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 11 | 4 | 19 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 71 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |
| 10 | 4 | 21 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 21.0 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MSj2KlZb)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above code but realized that it checks for row count to match with the grade %.  The first g1% of students need to be in grade1, next g2% of students need to be in grade 2 etc. I have modified my questions and removed my code to avoid confusion.

Comment: To be honest I would want to know more about  "rank". How is that determined?

Comment: first total of all the subjects are calculated and based upon the marks, they are ranked ((highest to lowest)). I used the rank function on marks field . 2 students can have the same rank

Comment: A revised answer provided - to be honest the prior answer had all the parts, it just needed combining it into a single query.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the previous answer worked as well just that I had missed to include cumulative % in you last answer and also the case statement seems to be different in postgres where if the 1st condition satisfies then it does not check the rest.

Comment: case is an **expression** (not a statement) but they work the same in all SQLs (if standard compliant) - as soon as a condition is met the case expression does not consider subsequent conditions.